# Calling a software from Matlab

Tags: matlab, system, command-prompt

The command prompt works well in all respect of running the software as well as generating reports and output files. To generate an ouput file containing the desired result, we have to run the executable of the report program which uses a parameter file. For example if I were to implement these steps in command prompt, it would be like this:

```
“path\report.exe” –f Report.rwd –o Report.rwo
```

The output file is Report.rwo, this file will contain the variable exported.

Now to implement this in Matlab, below is a small script giving a gist of what I am trying to achieve. It calls the software for each run and extracts the data.

```
for nr=1:NREAL

      dlmwrite(‘file.INC’,file(:,nr),’delimiter’,’\n’); % Writes the data file for each run

       system('"path\file.dat"');    % calls software
       system('"path\Report.rwd" –o "path\Report.rwo"'); % calls report

      [a,b]=textread(‘"path\Report.rwo".rwo’,’%f\t%f’); % Reads the data and store it in the variable b

end
```

So I have two problems:

1)  When I run this script in Matlab, it does not generate output file Report.rwo. Consequently, it gives an error when it reaches the line containing 'textread' function because of absence of the file.

2) Everytime Matlab calls a report (.rwd file), it prompts me to hit enter or type 'q' to quit. If suppose there are hundreds of files to run, then for every file I would be prompted to hit enter to proceed. The following line causes the prompt:

```
system('"path\Report.rwd" –o "path\Report.rwo"'); % Calls report
```

**OLDER EDIT:** There are 2 updates to my problem as follow:

**Update 1:** It seems that part 2 of my problem above has been resolved by Jacob. It is working fine for one run. However the final outcome will be confirmed only when I am able to run whole of my program which involves running hundreds of files.

**Update 2:** I can run the software and generate output file using command-prompt as follow:

```
**“path\mx200810.exe” –f file.dat**
```

- This command reads the report parameter file and generates output file:

  **“path\report.exe” –f Report.rwd –o Report.rwo**

**LATEST EDIT:**

1) I am able to run the software, avoid the prompt to hit the return key and generate the output file using Matlab through the following commands:

```
system('report.exe /f Report.rwd /o Report.rwo')
system('mx200810.exe -f file.dat')
```

However, I was able to do it only after copying my required .exe and .dll files in the same folder where I have my .dat file. So I am running the .m file through the same folder where I have all these files.

2) However there is still one error in Matlab's command window which says this:

```
"...STOP: Unable to open the following file as data file:
              'file.dat'
              Check path name for spaces, special character or a total length greater than 256 characters

              Cannot find data file named 'file.dat'

Date and Time of End of Run: .....

ans = 0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings enclosed in `" .. "` are invalid in MATLAB so I do not know how your `system` functions can even function.

Replace all `"` with `'` and then update your question and include the command line arguments (e.g.`-f file.dat`) inside the quotes as below:

```
  %# Calls software
  system('"path\mx200810.exe" –f file.dat'); 

  %# Calls report
  system('"path\report.exe" –f Report.rwd –o Report.rwo');
```

#### Update:

Here's a cheap trick to solve your second problem (type `q` to terminate the program):

```
  %# Calls software
  system('"path\mx200810.exe" –f "path\file.dat" < "C:\inp.txt"'); 

  %# Calls report   
  system('"path\report.exe" –f "path\Report.rwd" –o "path\Report.rwo" < "C:\inp.txt"');
```

1. Create a file (e.g. `C:\inp.txt`) which contains the letter `q` followed by the return character. You can create this by opening Notepad, typing `q`, hitting the return key and saving it as `C:\inp.txt`. This will serve as the "input" `report.exe` seems to need.
2. Change all the `system` calls in your code so that the input from the text file we just made is piped into it. I've included the modified calls above (scroll to the end to see the difference).

Comment: I've included a "trick" which might solve your second problem

Comment: Are you sure that the locations of `"C:\Program Files\CMG\IMEX\2008.10\Win32\EXE\mx200810.exe"` and `"C:\Program Files\CMG\BR\2008.10\Win32\EXE\report.exe"` are correct?

Comment: Have you enclosed the new path of `inp.txt` in `"` as well?

Comment: But since you've changed the path, to something with spaces in it, enclose it. E.g.  `"C:\Users\Harpreet Harpreet\Desktop\inp.txt"`

Comment: `"C:\Users\Harpreet Harpreet\Desktop\inp.txt"` was an example. You should replace it with the full path of `inp.txt` on your Desktop. This can be obtained by right-clicking the file and looking at its properties. The full path will be next to **Location**.

Comment: Yes, the `<` should be outside `"..."` since `"..."` should only enclose file paths with spaces in them.

Comment: OK, so we're getting somewhere. I've updated my answer to add a pipe out (`> "C:\inp.txt"`). This will dump any error messages to `"C:\err.txt"`. Change the path to whatever works for you.

Comment: Also, try replacing `CMGfile.dat`,`ReportBHP.rwd` and `ReportBHP.rwo` with the full paths. i.e., `"C:\Some Path\ReportBHP.rwd"` ; maybe the output files are created but in some other location.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to enclose them in quotes if the paths contain spaces just like `inp.txt`. And yes, `err.txt` will store error messages, and no problem :)

Comment: OK, sorry about that. Remove the output pipe and keep the full paths for `CMGfile.dat,ReportBHP.rwd` and `ReportBHP.rwo` --- I've updated my answer as well

Comment: Are you sure the output file is generated by you just typing `q` and hitting the return key? Also, how did you create `inp.txt`? Give me the exact details.

Comment: I've created a txt file which has `Q` and a return key --- try this:

http://download200.mediafire.com/3y00q90wtt9g/ij1m0tmijum/inp.txt

Comment: So what's the exact sequence of operations you do? Could you list them out in your answer? As in, run `mx200810.exe`, then run `report.exe`, hit `Q`, hit return, etc. Just give it all in detail so I have the right picture.

Comment: So if you ran the software normally without using `inp.txt`, would the `.row` file be generated?

Comment: Also, are you sure that the the `.row` file is **not** generated? Or is it just that `textread` is unable to find it?

Comment: Then there's nothing I can do. I was working under the assumption that you *could* generate the `.rwo` file and I tried to duplicate your actions. I suggest you look at the documentation of `report.exe` (which I think generates the required file) and see what's going on. Did you put down the **full path** of `ReportBHP.rwo` so that you know where to look?

Comment: Wait, so when running from the command prompt with the same command the output file is generated?

Comment: If so, could you include what you typed at the command prompt which seemed to generate the output file?

Comment: Can you update the question with the latest version? With the full paths for the `.rwo` files, etc.?

Comment: Try replacing the path in `textread` with the full path, i.e. `"C:\Documents and Settings\HSingh2\Desktop\Work\Model - SGEMS, CMG and MATLAB\ReportBHP1.rwo"`

Comment: And you're positive `"C:\Documents and Settings\HSingh2\Desktop\Work\Model - SGEMS, CMG and MATLAB\ReportBHP1.rwd"` exists?

Answer (score 1):

Use both outputs to get status of system run and text result, if any will be available.

```
cmd_line = '“path\report.exe” –f Report.rwd –o Report.rwo';
[status, result] = system(cmd_line);
```

Continue your script depending on `status` variable. Stop if it over then zero.

```
if (status)
    error('Error running report.exe')
end
[a,b]=textread(...
```

If your parameters are variable you can generate the command line string in MATLAB using string concatenation or [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) function.

Comment: cmd_line is MATLAB variable. Do no put it in quotes. Use `[status, result] = system(cmd_line)`.

Comment: Did you assign a command string to `cmd_line` before calling `system`?

Comment: This is strange. Try to run `class(cmd_line)`, will it return `char`? Try to put your command string directly to system call as the argument.

Comment: Are you sure you can run that command outside of MATLAB? From command prompt?

Comment: Will your program work correctly, if you run it from command prompt from the folder, which is current in MATLAB? You can find the folder running `pwd` in MATLAB. May be you should first change the workin directory to where your input files located with `cd dirname`. Or include full path of input files into command line.

Comment: What about if you try to call from MATLAB some other program? Something general like Wordpad: `"c:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe" somefilename.txt`. First try to make it work from command prompt. Then through system in MATLAB. Let us know if it works, and if not, what will be the error messages.

Comment: Try also to use exclamation point (!, http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-12994.html#f0-38522) to run external program from MATLAB. It 's easier then `system`. Everything you enter after ! symbol passed to OS. Just type `!“C:\Program Files\CMG\BR\2008.10\Win32\EXE\report.exe” –f ReportBHP.rwd –o ReportBHP.rwo`.

Comment: Try it also with the wordpad test.

Comment: This is just an example. I gave the path how it's on my computer. Yours might be different and wordpad may not be installed. Just to try something that should work for sure.

Comment: How long does it usually take for the programs to generate the output files? If you just run mx200810 from MATLAB, may be it will pass the control back to MATLAB, but the output will be generated later? Can you check that?